# Trouble using ExpressJS Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, body-parser

I'm in the early stages of writing a login form using NodeJS/Express. The server is getting the right information, but the response isn't getting to the client.

ExpressJS Server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();
const port = 3030;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.use(express.static(__dirname))

app.post('/login',(req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send({ status: 'SUCCESS' })
})

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Port: " + port)
})
```

---

On the client side:

```js
formLogin.onsubmit = async () => {
    validateLogin() // My validate login func
    validatePassword() // My validate pass func
    if (loginCorrect && hasloCorrect) {
        const formData = new FormData(formLogin)

        for (let [keyValue, value] of formData) {
            const encrypt = new safeData(value)
            await encrypt.setAsyncData()

            formData.set(keyValue,encrypt.encryptedData)
        } // also my methods,classes 

        // fetch to server 
        const reqheader = new Headers();
        reqheader.append("Content-Type", "text/html");

        const reqBody = new URLSearchParams(formData)
        const url = "http://127.0.0.1:3030/login";

        fetch(url, {
            method : "POST",
            body: reqBody,
        })

    } else {
    }

    return false
}
```

I've tried to set header to fetch function. On the server, I tried to use `res.redirect()` to `/login` instead of using `res.send()`. When I tried to send data from the FetchAPI. Using an HTML format to submit the data works correctly.

Comment: **Here are some tips for your first StackOverflow post:**

**(1)** Dont include annotations in your code fences, unless they are comments
**(2)** Define the language in your code fence so that the code is highlighted correctly
**(3)** Don't use all-caps for things that don't need it
**(4)** Correctly format inline code
**(5)** Don't ask "does anybody knows what's wrong" or similar questions; that is already implied by your post
**(6)** Use a spell checker

Comment: Also fix your title please

Answer (score -1):

There are several things to clarify, and hopefully you will find the solution you are looking for:

1. This issue has nothing to do with your server – it literally always responds with the same data, nothing can possibly be wrong with it.
2. Before I fixed the title of the post, you mentioned the body parser: again, this has nothing to do with your issues.
3. The body parser is a middleware function that **only** parses the request body. **It has nothing to do with providing responses.**
4. JavaScript does not spit out compile-time errors. If you want that, then you'll need TypeScript.
5. The Fetch API is [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous), so you will need a response handler for the HTTP request.
6. Using the Fetch API (or any other library) will perform **only** HTTP requests.
7. HTTP requests cannot directly control browser navigation (i.e. redirects, rendering HTML, consuming JSON/XML, etc)